# index.html not rendering saying unexpected token I can't find

Tags: reactjs

Following a tutorial on React NodeJS and also using mySQL.. Somewhere in completing the CRUD and going back to the Front End in React my page isn't rendering anymore.

the console in the browser is giving these 2 errors:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' manifest.json:1 Manifest:
> Line: 1, column: 1, Syntax error.

repository here: https://github.com/FikaKarin/LIBRARY

Comment: That error indicates your server is returning html instead of json when the manifest.json is request. This usually means your server is misconfigured, or the url being used to request the json is incorrect.

Comment: What do you get if you hit the `manifest.json` url directly? If it 404's (or otherwise errors) your server might be returning an html error page instead of json, which would trigger the error you're seeing. (You might also be able to see the response in the network tab of the browser's devtools.)